# List of Inventor versions supported by Autodesk Platform Services

Tags: forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor, aps

Can someone help me by sharing the list of Inventor versions supported by APS?
I'm using Design Automation API and Visualization API.

I tried this API https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/engines-GET/.
It returned a list with "Autodesk.Inventor+22", but when I tried to work with a model in Inventor 2022, I received an exception similar to future version error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the version information helps at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/change_history/inventor_release_notes/ .